# Angular2 - how to export and import correctly from typescript typing definition file?

Tags: typescript, angular

Assume I have a lib published to NPM, with only one line:

```
// file name index.js
function myLib(x) {return x;}
```

Want to import it to `app.component.ts` of this repo

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

After `npm install myLib`, and create `index.d.ts` file into `node_modules/myLib/` as

```
export default function myLib (x: any): any;
// or 
// declare function myLib (x: any): any;
// export default myLib;
```

Below is my QUESTIONS:

**Q1.Consume it in `app.component.ts` as:**

```
import myLib from 'myLib'
console.log( myLib )
```

The result is `undefined`, why?

**Q2.If change code as below:**

```
import * as myLib from 'myLib'
console.log( myLib )
```

The result is `function myLib(x) {return x;}`, seems right, but

```
console.log( myLib(123) )
```

Webpack show an error message:

> src/app/app.component.ts:12:21
>
> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

What the hell?

Thanks!!